# Unable to access /review page when logged in, works fine when not logged in

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, review

**When I'm logged in:**

Earlier today I attempted to go to `/review` on Super User, only to a Page Not Found error. As the day progressed, this has not changed. Logging in and out has done nothing. Different browsers have not changed a thing.

I have tried to go to `/review/close` and other sub locations, with the same results.

Other sites are not having this issue for me, just Super User.

What's going on?

[image]

**When I'm not logged in:**

I can see it when logged out. Is that supposed to happen?

[image]

Comment: I see it fine not logged in, FF8.

Comment: They (the devs) have been making a lot of changes to how `/review` works, as well as the moderator tools. It works for me, (logged in or not) can you confirm? I tried on the latest (stable) Chrome and FF

Comment: @TimPost I've asked around, it seems to be working for others, although they were all moderators. No other users seem to have that issue. I've tested this on the Latest Firefox, as well as my iPod Touch's Safari browser.

Comment: I just tried on my wife's laptop (IE, Chrome and FF) and I can't reproduce it. So I snagged her Galaxy tab, same result. This is strange. I've never logged into a SE site using either, at least that I can remember.

Comment: @TimPost I'm finding it very odd too. And its ONLY on Super User for me

Comment: I get the same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am guessing you were both reviewing questions with close votes earlier - it seems this has been restricted to 10k users now as I can't access it but could before.

The /review page remembers which tab you were last reviewing when you go back to it, so in this case it's remembering you were on the close votes view, but now you can't access it - hence the error message.

If you go here it should reset what your last tab is:

> https://superuser.com/review/first-answers

Comment: confirmed ... that was the bug ... also just checked in a fix ... to be deployed soon

Comment: @waffles will we be getting that privilege back to view the VTC's?

Comment: as soon as you hit 10k you will ...

Comment: @waffles ah.. Kinda sucks, was such a nice thing for 3k+ users..

Answer (score 2):

I get the same problem. (Here's to prove that Simon isn't crazy.) :P

[image]