# Why is the /review page available to unregistered users?

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

Right click this link -> https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers <- and open it in an incognito window (or whatever the FF equivalent is).  It works.

Waffles said [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110935/have-the-review-link-appear-for-anyone-with-the-deputy-badge/111010#111010) that the review page should be

> completely shut for any users with less than 1000 rep, including making it not accessible via the URL.

I believe that the above quote was just an opinion, but  I understood that the previous requirement was 200 rep, and, if I remember my mathematics correctly, 0 is less than 200.

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111709) was marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), in spite of the fact that it points out that the review page is available without being logged in at all, so the team isn't oblivious to the problem.

What's the expected behavior here?  I'm quite confident that this page shouldn't be accessible to unregistered users, so I'm marking this as a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

Comment: MSO was down when I wanted to ask this, so I'm migrating it.  Sorry for the migration noise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of these changes are making a coherent answer from me, tricky business.

I changed it ... yet again ... so `/review` is blocked for anon and people without the [new user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user) priv.

I agree, it makes no sense to give them access.

However, once you start participating I think it is fine, since you get badge progress for `strunk and white`.